# Font / SVG rendering artifacts in Sencha Touch / Android

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2, rendering, android-browser

I have the following problem: the Android browser renders font and SVG artefacts in a webpage made with Sencha Touch 2.

It seems to re-render every card in a `Ext.navigation.View` after a short delay (approx. 0.5s) and only then the artefacts show. Also, not all text seems to be affected.

Does anyone recognize this behaviour and knows how to tackle the problem?

*As for the SVG problem, I found a weird workaround by replacing one of the SVG images with a PNG equivalent, but I'd really like to know what is causing the artefacts to occur.*

**Examples** (artefacts/reference):

[image: Font rendering artifact]

[image: Font rendering without artifact]

[image: SVG rendering artifact]

[image: SVG rendering without artifact]

*All buttons are styled with `background-image: url(file.svg)`*

Comment: As this question earned me the Tumbleweed badge, I chose to go for the workaround and replaced SVG with PNG, which is not as sharp given that it's being resized in the browser, but at least it looks better than a blurred SVG. Still curious for what could be triggering this behaviour! :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, was excited to find this SO post, but just as disappointed to see that it's a tumbleweed without solution.

Comment: I found some alleged options for this here (duplicate issue?): http://stackoverflow.com/a/14624756/1422164

Comment: Did this work for you? I suspect it's a different issue (font-related, and possibly only related to Sencha)