# Sencha touch + WP8 + Cordova - icon font not shown - Workaround

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch

Latest sencha touch is using webfonts for icons but WP8 has some limitation with web fonts see [Using css font-face in a Phonegap Windows Phone 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575208/using-css-font-face-in-a-phonegap-windows-phone-8-app/14624756#14624756)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 1 day i just found simple workaround. Since sencha touch has different css for win and android we are doing next.
To all our icons i am adding class win

```
{
                        align: 'left',
                        name: 'nav_btn',
                        iconCls: 'list win',
                        ui: 'plain'
                    },
```

Then in win.scss (or css it doesnot matter )

```
.list.win {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,BASE64ICON');
}
```

but in that case it will show content letter so to fix it

```
.x-tab .x-button-icon.list.win:before,
.x-button .x-button-icon.list.win:before,
.x-tab .x-button-icon.settings.win:before,
.x-button .x-button-icon.settings.win:before{
  content: none;
}
```

Its not the best solution but not its just fixed my problem..

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Volodymyr answer, I would suggest using a mixin to avoid repeating css code, and leveraging the `x-windowsphone` class that Sencha applies to the body on Windows Phone. Result is much more compact:

```
@mixin windowsphone-icon($name, $icon) {

    .x-tab .x-button-icon.#{$name}:before,
    .x-button .x-button-icon.#{$name}:before {
        content: none;
    }

    .x-button-icon.#{$name} {
        background-image: url(#{$icon});
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }

}

.x-windowsphone {

    @include windowsphone-icon('list', '../images/icons/list.png');

}
```

Comment: New to Sencha Touch. Where do I place this? Thank you.