# CSS custom font not working

Tags: css, fonts

I downloaded a font , I'm trying to create a banner in css and I need this font but it just doesn't show up.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Minecrafter;
    src: url("../fonts/Minecrafter_3.ttf") format('truetype');
}

#logo{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Minecrafter;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

Can I check for errors somehow? I'm developing a win8 app.

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Are you using Cordova/Phonegap?

Comment: i'm using visual studio

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using css font-face in a Phonegap Windows Phone 8 app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575208/using-css-font-face-in-a-phonegap-windows-phone-8-app)

Comment: it actually says this : failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different browsers support a different set of font formats, so you need to provide a set of alternatives for each browser (somw of the brwoser support *.eot*.woff *ttf) so you must proivde alternative src for you fonts :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Minecrafter;
    src: url("font.ttf") format('truetype');
         url("font.woff") format('woff');
}
```

good website for converting the font for the format you want :
https://onlinefontconverter.com

Comment: is the answer was helpful ?

Comment: @Endless editing old posts only to change `http://` to `https://` is not useful. Doing so bumps these old posts on the active tab and generally annoys people. Please see: ["**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) - from the help center page on editing.

Comment: thanks that onlinefontconverter is a great resource, much obliged