# Using Google Webfonts in Windows Phone 8 web browser control

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-phone, webfonts

I am trying to use web fonts in my Windows phone application. From the comments I have read, I understood that it is not possible to use fonts embedded into XAP file. So, I am trying to open a webpage that contains Google Web Fonts which is at: http://omercelik.com/e.htm

When I open this page from Internet Explorer on phone, it shows the font correctly. But when I try to load this page from a webBrowser control, it doesn't loads this page. I don't do anything else but this on my app:

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://omercelik.com/e.htm"));
    }
```

So, still no success to show custom fonts in my application. There are suggestions to host font remotely and cache but even without caching, I couldn't show fonts. Can someone provide a working example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to embed truetype fonts in Windows Phone 8 webapps by setting the embeddable tag on the font to 0 using software like [TTFEdit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ttfedit/). This might prove a more reliable and elegant solution to your problem.

See [my answer to another Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558331/getting-a-web-font-to-work-on-an-html5-windows-phone-app/20573678#20573678) question here for all the details.

Comment: This is the right answer. I created a repo with a sample app based on @thomasf2811 solution: https://github.com/gabrielmaldi/windows-phone-8-local-font-face

Answer (score 0):

When using the `WebBrowser` control, it's very important to include the HTML doctype if you want to get proper IE10 behaviour (ie. not quirks mode) in Windows Phone 8...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine);
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="para" style="font-family:'Tangerine', serif;">Making the Web Beautiful</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For future reference, Windows Phone 7's `WebBrowser` control (based on IE9) does not support Web Fonts.

Comment: This example works in Desktop IE10 but not when I run it in Cordova/PhoneGap.