# FontAwesome on windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, font-awesome

I am having trouble getting FontAwesome icons to show on Windows Phone 8.

- Phone (HTC 8X): OK on the dev box (http), but not on the QA server (https)
- Surface RT, Pro, desktop: OK on both servers

All devices use IE10. Both environments (Dev and QA) use IIS7. It seems that IE10 phone is somehow different from IE10 tablet/desktop in its treatment of downloadable fonts.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: The github demo site views fine in both WP8's IE10 and the `WebBrowser` control, [could it be a HTML doctype issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411808/using-google-webfonts-in-windows-phone-8-web-browser-control/15500622#15500622)

Answer (score 10):

It was due to a missing MIME type. I was wrong about both environments using IIS7; The QA server uses IIS6. We added `application/x-font-woff` to the IIS configuration, and that fixed it.

UPDATE:
Add this to your `Web.config` to associate .woff files with the correct MIME type, so the server will know what to do when such a file is requested:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @kadumel: I have updated the answer with more info on how to configure IIS to serve .woff files.

Comment: This is definitely the correct solution this also solved my problem under Azure. Thank you!