# Windows Phone 8 App doesn't show icon font, but the browser does

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, telerik, font-face, font-awesome

So I am creating an app.

I ran into the problem that the font awesome icons where shown as squares on the phone.

I already changed the Font embedding type to 0 as described in this topic:
[FontAwesome displaying as squares on WP8 using cordova/phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329784/fontawesome-displaying-as-squares-on-wp8-using-cordova-phonegap)

This did help for the phone's internal browser and the website looks OK now.

However using the app the issue still remains.

Do you know how to solve this?

In regard to Matt's question:
I am using the described way Font Awesome uses so:

```
<li class="fa fa-search"></li>
```

I changed the font-awesome CSS to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also the embedding of the font is changed with TTFEdit from 4 to 0

Comment: Can you show how you're setting the font in the app?

Comment: Hey @MattSmall yes I can, just added some more info in the question. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558331/getting-a-web-font-to-work-on-an-html5-windows-phone-app/20573678#20573678 and ensured that the file is being copied to the device when built and deployed.

Comment: There is also and article here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2014/03/15/how-to-use-custom-font-in-windows-phone-8-application.aspx that may be useful.

Comment: thanks @97ldave I am using telerik/cordova so I can't set the 'Build Action'to Content, though in Visual Studio that is the standard. Don't know if this copies the fonts, though I do think they do. I will have a look at the blog, hopefully it works.