# Onsen UI not displaying icons (wp8)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, onsen-ui, ionicons

I am working with a mobile app in Cordova using an onsen ui Framework.

After generating apk on windows phone application it works correctly, but does not display icons at all.
I use only Ionicons, not Font Awesome.

On other platforms (Android, IOS) icons work correctly.

Anyone can give me some suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding `wp8` platform or `windows`? Onsen UI works for Windows Universal Apps (`windows`).

Comment: wp8, the problem was not in the platform, only in the font face.
Here I found the solution: [Getting a web-font to work on an HTML5 Windows Phone App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558331/getting-a-web-font-to-work-on-an-html5-windows-phone-app?lq=1)

Comment: I am aware of that problem in wp8, but there are others. Onsen UI is only tested for Universal Apps, not for wp8.